# Newbie One Hard Disk Two OS X How To?

Tags: macos, multi-boot

I am a long time Windows User, but newbie on OS X

This is a wonderful OS I use.

I have a macbook pro with 500GB HDD inside.

I want to one HDD install both OS X 10.8.5 and OS X 10.10.2, plus one more partition for save data, so when as need, I format any two OS X partition will not data lose... (So Total 3 partition base on my case there).

But I search APPLE official KB, not find any document as example like my case, just only see how to install the OS X on ext HDD only (Not the way I want to be).

So .... anyone can tell me how to do above? OR can it?

MacBook Pro, OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5)

Comment: How you proceed depends on a few things. What model of MacBook Pro do you have? Do you currently have an OS installed on the internal hard drive?

Comment: The partitioning & install should be easy - see Disk Utility, in Applications/Utilities. Make sure you have a backup just in case. The difficult part might be getting hold of 10.8.5. Unless you already 'bought' it from the App Store, there's no way to get it from Apple.

Comment: @JimmyChan Please also add the fill level of your HDD and do you have an external hard disk?

Comment: I am using 2010 Mid 15"

Answer (score 1):

I final do this with disk utility, then partition with 4. Each with different name etc such as OS X 10.10, OS X 10.9, OS X 10.8 etc.

Then make the USB stick install OS X one by one and when installing choose install to which partition.